# using html tags inside echo plus calling data from a db

Tags: php, html, syntax, syntax-error

I want to know why this works:

```
echo "<p><b> Num : </b> $vrac[isbn] </p>";
```

and not this:

```
echo "<p><b> Num : </b> htmlentities($vrac[isbn],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') </p>";
```

**What I'm trying to do is print data from a table in my db using htmlentities so special characters can be converted to html characters(avoiding the ? replacment).**

P.S: The first code will print the data correctly, while the second code will print the data inside htmlentities(DATAHERE,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') as it is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, because you cant call functions inside string. Following is how you do it:

```
echo "<p><b> Num : </b> " . htmlentities($vrac['isbn'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') . " </p>";
```

Comment: Using this yields this error: ) `Notice: Use of undefined constant isbn - assumed 'isbn' in C:\wamp\www\possibleimages\catalogue.php on line 45`

Comment: This is just a warning. I updated my answer already, just wrap single quotes around isbn

Comment: I think it's fixed, I put isbn between ''